# zcash - current block reward

Tags: mining-reward, zcash

Zcash implements the `slow start` strategy, as described [here](https://z.cash/blog/new-alpha-release-mining-slow-start.html).

The reward for mining a block is meant to ramp up linearly and reach it's maximum value around block 5000.

How do I check the current reward value per block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to look at the latest block and see how much is the reward e.g. [block 5846](https://explorer.zcha.in/blocks/00000001f88f94adfacef15e211bd790ffc448b6ceeeeb9c7ac6afc112d8babc) has reward of 3.65385 ZEC

Or you can drectly see current reward here https://explorer.zcha.in/statistics